# Probability of r 1s in a subset of length d of a random vector

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, expectation

Given a random vector $X\in\{0,1\}^{N\times1}$ with $Pr[X_i=1]=p$ (essentially X is drawn from a binomial distribution with probability of success = p), let $X_d\subset X$ of length $d$. What is the probability that $n(X_d=1)=r$?

Comment: What are the joint distribution between the each components $X_i$? Are they independent or?

Comment: It's a binomial distribution...

Comment: @BGM as mentioned by Mostafa above, X is a binomial distribution with probability of success 'p'